# Can't get rid of one text message

Tags: sms

I have had this single text message on my phone since June. It simply won't delete. It comes through my Twitter account and is sent to my SMS, but all other such texts delete easily.

Comment: Maybe edit your answer to include your phone's make and model. Since every phone is different. But if you cant deleted it. It might be listed as a protected text or locked text. You might have to change the settings for it before you can delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Press your finger down on the message text until a menu comes up.  Unlock the message - that's how I was able to delete a message that would not delete the regular way.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the cache and data of messaging app should help. Also, clean the cache of other SMS apps including Hangouts if you have installed them.

Is this SMS is moved to SIM for some reason? I always backup and then clean and never keep in SIM.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send something on the same number/contact. It will add to the message thread. Then try to delete it.